# Need help installing program; can't get `make` to work in src directory

Tags: linux, installation, security, centos, make

I've been trying very hard to get John the Riper to work. I installed it on Ubuntu and it wouldn't work giving me an error about unknown cipher. Now I'm trying to install it on CentOS.

I tried installing it with from the command line

```
[root@localhost src]# yum install john
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.atwab.net
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: centos.mirrors.atwab.net
 * updates: centos.mirrors.atwab.net
No package john available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost src]#
```

`I downloaded jump package [from the official][1] website and decompressed but I can't get the`make`command to work. I go to the`/src/` folder and try to make it but

```
[dev@localhost src]$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[dev@localhost src]$ make generic
make: *** No rule to make target `generic'.  Stop.
```

I'm new to Linux.

Comment: There are two possible approaches here; not sure which you are asking about.  One approach is to try to enable a repository for `yum` which contains John the Ripper.  The other is to try to debug the source compilation on your system.  I'd recommend the first approach, but what version of CentOS are you using?

Comment: @Wildcard newest I believe, CentOS 3.10 64 bit (running on Vmware). How do you enable a repository for `yum`?

Comment: You add a text file with the proper syntax to the directory `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and ensure the filename ends in `.repo`.  (And that the file owner is root and the permissions match the other files in that directory.)  That's all there is to it.  The trick is to know which repo has what you want, and what text to include in the repo file for that repo.  For that, use Google.  ;)

Comment: Actually, I found it.  Posting answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Since the key is missing from the `john` package, you can skip downloading the GPG key for the dag repo and just change the dag repo text to `gpgcheck=0`.  Or you can follow these steps in full anyways, so you can install signed packages from the dag repo in the future.

---

`yum install john` will only work if you have a yum software repository configured which includes the package `john`.

For CentOS, the package is available in the `dag` repo.

Paste the following into a text file using your favorite text editor:

```
[dag]
name=DAG RPM Repository
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
```

Save it as `dag.repo`.

Next, run the following commands:

```
sudo chown root:root dag.repo
sudo chmod 644 dag.repo
sudo mv dag.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Next is to download the GPG key for the dag repo.  (Skip this if you changed gpgcheck to 0 in the above text.)

```
cd /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/
sudo wget apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

Your dag repo is now configured.  Note that it is NOT enabled; you could accomplish that by changing the last line in the text above to `enabled=1`.  However, best practices dictate you shouldn't enable third party repos by default; otherwise strange things will happen when you next `yum update` and things can break.  (Been there, done that.)

Instead of globally enabling it, you can enable a repo on a per-command basis like so.  I've also added the flag to disable gpgcheck, since the john package is missing a signature:

```
sudo yum install john --enablerepo=dag --nogpgcheck
```

And voila!  John will now be installed on your system.  ;)

Comment: Note that it is fine to enable the repo by editing that line in the repo file, but be sure you disable it again when you are done using the repo.  If crucial packages like C libraries get downloaded from a third party repo, you can end up with compatibility issues.  And there's really no reason to edit the repo file when you only want one specific package.

Comment: It still says `bash: john: command not found...` when I ran `yum install john --enablerepo=dag` the last message was `Public key for john-1.7.9-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm is not installed`

Comment: Whoops, forgot the public key!  Fixed.

Comment: Still same error :/

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear; the missing GPG key prevented the package from *installing* correctly, so you need to run `sudo yum install john` again.  Or do you mean the "Public key not installed" error showed up again?

Comment: Yes I did run `sudo yum install john` and still "Public key not installed" error showed up again

Comment: It also says `warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/dag/packages/john-1.7.9-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 6b8d79e6: NOKEY`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29961/discussion-between-wildcard-and-celeritas).